# 4m Rows in MySQL, ~5 Minutes to Run Query

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I have 2 tables, a users table and a log table which literally logs each time a user signs in.

What I'm trying to do is grab a list of all users with a certain rank who have not logged in for over a year. That said, I have a working query, but it's taking ~5 minutes to execute.

Here's what I'm currently working with:
<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a599f/1/0)</kbd>

```
SELECT u.usrid, u.username, u.rank, u.extras, l.dtime 
FROM users AS u
JOIN (
    SELECT userid, MAX(datetime) dtime 
    FROM log 
    GROUP BY userid
) AS l
ON u.usrid = l.userid 
WHERE (u.rank = 'P' OR u.extras LIKE '%W%')
AND l.dtime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
ORDER BY l.dtime DESC
```

It's a part of a very old and soon to be updated system... But until then, I'm trying to make the best of what I've been given to work with. That being said, I don't have access to actually alter the database schema so I'm hoping there is a way to optimize this query to work better.

Furthermore, the users table has ~500k rows while the log table has ~4m rows. With that many rows, I'm also wondering if it's a size issue. If so, what suggestions could I pass on to the DBA in order to improve it's ability to scale? I know I could simply store the last log in date somewhere separate for this particular use-case; but we use that log data for a lot of things so we need a way to be able to search it efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  u.usrid, u.username, u.rank, u.extras, x.dtime
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  userid, MAX(datetime) dtime
            FROM  log
            GROUP BY  userid
            HAVING  dtime < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
      ) AS x
    JOIN  users u ON u.usrid = x.userid
    WHERE  ( u.rank = 'P'
              OR  u.extras LIKE '%W%' 
           )
    ORDER BY  x.dtime DESC
```

Plus

```
 INDEX(usrid, datetime) -- in `log`
```

(I assume `usrid` is the `PRIMARY KEY` in `users`.)

Is size an issue?  Yes and no.  With the right indexes and queries, etc, billion-row tables can work fine.  In your case, it is dubious...  The subquery will probably produce 500K distinct users from its `GROUP BY`.  Then the `HAVING` will shrink the number.  What's left needs to be looked up in `users` and further filtered.  Finally another sort (`ORDER BY`) before delivering the results.

I *think* that newer versions of MySQL will leapfrog through the `INDEX` I suggested, landing on only 500K index rows, not all 4M.

If you think the `rank` and `extras` do a better filtering than `MAX(datetime)`, then a different approach might be faster.

Comment: Thanks. This query took 62 seconds to run as opposed to the 247 seconds my original one averaged. Definitely an improvement! I'll send a message to our DBA to see about adding that index to test it further. I'm going to leave the question open for now to see if anyone else cares to answer. Oh, and the rank/extras in this particular use-case would narrow it to ~100 users in total. If it's not too much, I'd like to see the alternative approach.

Comment: The INDEX is likely to give you a big improvement.